# Is it possible to be integrate Alexa Skills Kit with iOS mobile app to trigger a event?

Tags: ios, mobile, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

For example, say I want to launch camera within my ios app to take a photo, Can I utilize ASK and iphone microphone to understand users speech command("launch camera") to launch camera and trigger a function within ios?

Comment: You're better off using something like [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx) for basic command and control speech recognition. What you mentioned is not really ideal with Alexa since you have to make a lot of roundtrips.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Yes, but not really a good us case.

The Alexa Skills Kit is used to create an endpoint (skill) that the Alexa service can invoke to do something. The Alexa Skills Kit does not cover the acquisition and recognition of the speech. That all happens within the Alexa service.

The Alexa *Voice* Kit is a newly released kit that lets you do the other end. You can use it to integrate anything with a microphone into the Alexa service. Using this kit you can stream raw sound recorded from your microphone up to the service, and it will do the recognition and invocation of services.

So, in theory, you could use the Alexa Voice Kit and enable your iphone as a device that could send sound and invoke Alexa skills. You could use the Alexa Skill Kit to enable a web service that can be invoked by Alexa. You could do some sort of push/pull notification between your web service and your phone to trigger whatever you want. Then you would be able to invoke your Alexa skill with your iPhone, and have it do something on your iPhone.

Probably not where you really want to go. The better way to implement that use case is to use whatever speech recognition and trigger options iOS gives you and not via Alexa.